# React Native - optimising ReactJS code for a timer app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, timer

I'm currently moving my ReactJS code to React Native and I was wondering if I need to update it in any way.
It's working but I believe there might be a memory leak somewhere (I get a warning when running the app).

The part I'm referring to is:

```js
class Stopwatch extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      timerOn: false,
      timerStart: 0,
      timerTime: 0
    };
  }

  startTimer = () => {
        this.setState({
          timerOn: true,
          timerTime: this.state.timerTime,
          timerStart: Date.now() - this.state.timerTime,
        });
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
          this.setState({
            timerTime: Date.now() - this.state.timerStart
          });
        }, 10);
      };
    
    stopTimer = () => {
        this.setState({ 
          timerOn: false,
        });
        clearInterval(this.timer);
      };


    render() {
        return (
              <View>
                  {this.state.timerOn === false && this.state.timerTime === 0 && (
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.startTimer}>
                      <Text>start</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity> 
                  )}
                  {this.state.timerOn === true && (
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.stopTimer}>
                      <Text>stop</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  )}
              </View>
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What's the warning that you're getting?

Comment: @vijaykrishna 
"Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, 
the componentWillUnmount method"

It may be something else but I wanted to start with checking the timer part of my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your component unmounts while the timer is running you will find a memory leak. This is because the setInterval never gets cleared; the interval callback will still fire, and since it calls setState it will try to update the component even though it is no longer mounted (leading to the error message)

To solve this you just need to use the componentWillUnmount lifecycle method to clear the setInterval.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: There is a stopTimer function that aims to clear the interval - is it not enough in this case?

Comment: The `stopTimer` function is good, but right now it doesn't get called if the `Stopwatch` component is unmounted while the timer is still running, hence the warning about the memory leak. Calling `stopTimer` in the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method will ensure the timer is cleaned up before the component is unmounted.

Comment: Yeah, as @azundo said, calling stopTimer in componentWillUnmount will be enough 

Comment: Brilliant! Would you mind giving my answer an upvote and mark it’s the correct answer? 

Comment: Also, I fixed another issue I had with the app and I thought it's because of the said memory loss. 
Upon clicking start button, the app was slowing down and the stop button needed couple seconds to execute. However, after changing the interval from 10 to 1000 (in my case full seconds are enough) I stopped seeing lags. I guess another lesson for me is to buy a better laptop :D

Comment: Unrelated to the original question but you might want to check out `requestAnimationFrame` for updating a timer value to avoid `setInterval`s piling up `setState`s and causing slowdowns like the one you're talking about. If you're going to be displaying the time you will want to update the value much more than once per second otherwise the timer will often seem to lag and skip values since `setInterval` does not guarantee it will run exactly at the interval you specify.